# Grails changing case of table names when switching from H2 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails application that has been working properly with an H2 database for months.  All of the table names and column names are in uppercase.  I switched to MySQL when moving into production and the application stopped working.  Even simple things like counting the number of rows for a table returned 0.  I know that I am successfully connecting to the MySQL database so I don't think that is an issue.

When I looked at the table contents in a GUI I noticed that additional tables were being created that were named similarly but all lowercase instead of uppercase.  So my good data is all under Table 'FOO' but my Grails app is looking in 'foo' (which is empty) according to the Hibernate queries that are dumped to the console.  I did not change anything in my Grails settings other than the url (which was updated to point to the MySQL database instead of the H2 database), the driver class (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver),and the dialect (org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect)

The application is also doing the same thing to the column names.  I checked my MySQL server settings and My lower_case_table_names variable is set to 0.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Why not rename all your tables to lower case?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that because I am disposed to be lazy :)  After looking at the Grails manual I can see that the convention is automatically chosen as lowercase by the GORM.  I am not sure why it used uppercase with H2 though.  Maybe it had something to do with the H2 dialect.